# How to instantly show the uptime for a group of servers in my intranet on Linux?

Tags: linux, networking

I am not looking for sniffering tools, but quickly show the uptime for some servers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can send a command when initiating an SSH connection which will be executed and then exit, eg:

ssh

or

```
jim@mybox:~$ ssh localhost uptime
 11:57:16 up 24 days,  1:10, 59 users,  load average: 2.35, 1.83, 2.00
```

If you setup some SSH keys you could have a script poll the servers pretty quickly.

Comment: wow, this indeed is an easy and quick way. Thanks. One problem though, if the server happens to be down, the command will hang there for a few seconds, I imagine if I write a bash script for about 20 servers, I might get a quite slow response.

Comment: `for $server in $(cat servers); do ssh $server "hostname;uptime" &; done`
Your output can get a little garbled but at least you will not have downtime for offline servers and you will know what server each uptime refers to. `servers` is a file with the server names or ip addresses for `ssh` to connect.

Comment: Perhaps you could ping the host first to see if it is alive, then only execute the ssh if the ping succeeds? eg: `ping -c 1 -w 1 localhost && ssh localhost uptime`

Comment: Another way: Let each server send its output to the monitoring server instead.

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: configure SNMP on clients and write a script which will ask servers to report their uptime via SNMP OID
http://www.debianadmin.com/linux-snmp-oids-for-cpumemory-and-disk-statistics.html
You can also monitor other things

Answer (score 1):

rwhod(8)  is a special network service for that purpose. ruptime(1) gives a status line like uptime for each machine on the local network

Answer (score 0):

Configure passwordless ssh (with public keys) and execute the check in batch mode (execute *uptime*.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use a monitoring system like [ZABBIX](http://www.zabbix.com/) or [Nagios](http://www.nagios.org/) to keep track of uptimes as well as a bunch of other useful parameters.